# How to retrieve more specific errors from Auth::attempt()

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a strange experience with laravels Auth::attempt.

I made a signup page for users and everything works fine, you can:

- sign up
- validate email
- sign in
- etc

Now the weird part is that Auth::attempt() works fine with any data input except when I use my own e-mailaddress. So I have brought it down to this one specific address not getting through Auth::attempt(), but now I can't think of any reason for it to go wrong with just this one while anything else is fine.

So my question is: How can I get more specific feedback from Auth::attempt() for troubleshooting?

Comment: isn't it helpful if you write the tests?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me. What tests?