# How to display specific errors when loggin in in a Laravel 5.3 app with the Auth::attempt()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

My question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104229/how-to-retrieve-more-specific-errors-from-authattempt) but I'm not getting any error when logging in. I'm using `Auth::attempt()` to log users in my app but it returns `false` if authentication fails without giving a clue to whether was the email or the password that were incorrect. What I need to know is if it is possible to get specific errors in this situation. I've been all over the documentation but it failed to provide answers so far. I know that I can create a message bag and return it with a custom message but what I would like is to return specific message much like the `validator`does. Something like this:

```
[
    'password' => 'This password is incorrect'
]
```

or

```
[
    'email' => 'This email doesn\'t exist'
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to catch it yourself

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
if ( !$user ) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'This email doesn\'t exist'
    ]);
}

if( Auth::attemp(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $request->password]) ) {
    //Logging successful
    return redirect()->to('dashboard');
}

//if you get to this line, login failed
return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
    'password' => 'This password is incorrect'
]);
```